# Magento 2. Technical Guidelines. Module Version Dependency Question

Tags: magento2, magento-core

I am looking at the official docs [here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/versioning/dependencies.html)

Why is it that when changing the **preference** of a **class** marked with `@api` you can depend on a **MAJOR** version but when you change the preference of an **interface** marked with `@api` you have to depend on a **MINOR** version release. Is it not kinda the same thing?

Same thing goes for implementing an **interface** (depend on **MINOR**) and **extending** a concrete **class** (depend on **MAJOR**) both marked with `@api`

What is the reasoning behind this?

IMHO implementing an interface should not make me more dependent on a module than extending a concrete class.

Comment: It feels weird to me too... shouldn't it be other way around?

Comment: I think they should have the same dependency level, whichever might that be @VivekKumar

Comment: In my opinion, the interface is being used as a service contract so it must not be changed that often and hence should be MAJOR but the concrete implementation may change to add/improve a feature so that can be a MINOR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm leaving here a possible answer, more of an assumption.

Regarding the **preference** issue the assumption is that the rewrite class is extending the original class, so if a method is added to the original class the rewrite will inherit it. As for the **preference** of an interface, if a method is added to the interface, the code will break.

To the other one implementing and interface vs extending a class the same principle applies, if a method is added to the interface the code will break, but if adding a method is added to the parent class the method will be inherited and the code will not break.

This however does not apply to case in which a method is added to the concrete class and there already exists such a method in the child class with a different signature. Or if in the parent class an abstract method is added.

Answer (score 1):

I also read the same technical documentation while ago and came to the same conclusion. On the surface it doesn't make sense.

A year or so later and I'm still confused by it.

My best guess is someone at Magento was trying to preemptively predict that certain areas were going to undergo a significant change.

Personally I've rarely coded something that depends on a certain version. And if I face incompatibility I create a different version of the file(s) to work with that particular version. Model21.php, Model22.php, Model23.php etc Wyomind take similar approach. It's a bit untidy but gets the job done. Plus your code is still readable.  Just means you need someone with a bit of knowledge to install extension especially if you bundle all the files together.

But I'll admit I haven't produced anything too revolutionary. I generally try to work within the realms of the framework.

Comment: Hi Dominic. Thank you for your answer. The trouble is they ask this kind of questions in the Certification exam. Is harder to remember smth that does not make sense.

Comment: are you preparing for developer plus certification? @vitoriodachef

Comment: No. But I have plenty of experience with these type exams. Before I became a web developer at an agency I worked an an IT trainer and taught CIW https://www.ciwcertified.com/  plus did the odd bit of freelance. Although the topics change the methods of testing and creating a certification / exam are the same.

Comment: @aravind Just developer

Comment: I am also preparing for the same..@vitoriodachef

Comment: @DominicXigen It appears that no one is providing another answer. Thank you for the time you put in, answering this questions. I'm awarding the bounty to you.